# How to add image explanation under the image?

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

```html
<html>

<style>
  #MCALPmainArticleBox {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 980px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 26px;
    float: left;
  }
  
  #MCALPmainArticleBoxImg {
    width: 384px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    float: left;
  }
</style>


<div id="MCALPmainArticleBox">
  <a href="#"><img id="MCALPmainArticleBoxImg" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Goemetry.jpg" </a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
</div>

</html>
```

I have coded these codes above. That is not enough for me to add some info about the image just below it. (red text on the image). Rest of the black text should be wrap both image and red text. Thank for your help.

I want this:

[image]

Comment: I want this. http://oi63.tinypic.com/vyslg6.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```css
#MCALPmainArticleBox {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 980px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 26px;
  float: left;
}   

#MCALPmainArticleBoxImg {
  width: 384px;
  padding-right: 16px;

}
```

```html
<div id="MCALPmainArticleBox">
<a href="#"><img id="MCALPmainArticleBoxImg" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Goemetry.jpg"> </a>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</p>  
    </div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxta5ub5/)

Is this the same that you want as your output?

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you Bhawin. But that is not i am looking for. I need the thing in this image : http://oi63.tinypic.com/vyslg6.jpg The red text is related with the image and that black text should wrap bot the image and the red text. Thanks again.

Comment: Or this image: https://s11.postimg.org/8nbq51brn/Image9.jpg Bot image and the explanation text just under it should be wrapped by the main text.

Comment: i guess @wigi has answered your question as per your need. is it the same that you want?

Comment: Thank you for your care to my question Bhavin. You are right. What the codes that Wigi wrote are what i need.

Comment: that's fine. glad that you got the output that you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a new `span` which contains the label for the image and changed some CSS for the existing elements.

```css
#MCALPmainArticleBox {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 980px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 26px;
  
}   

#MCALPmainArticleBoxImgOuter{
  display:block;
  width: 384px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#MCALPmainArticleBoxImg{
  max-width:100%;
}

.imageLabel{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="MCALPmainArticleBox">
  <a href="#" id="MCALPmainArticleBoxImgOuter">
    <img id="MCALPmainArticleBoxImg" src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-480x270-Goemetry.jpg">
    <span class="imageLabel">Some label for the image</span>
    </a>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu<br>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligu<br>
  </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much wigi. That is what i exactly needed. :) Have a nice week.

Comment: Oh, i now realized that there is something missing related with what i want. The red text link and the image's link have the same url. But the image's url should go the url (someurl) where the rest of the black text (complete article) belongs and the red text's url should go to the image's copyright owner's url. Thank you.

Comment: Just replace the current `<a>` tag by a `<div>` and wrap two different `<a>` tags around the image and image label.

Comment: @Makas remember to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted when it answered your question(s) :)

Comment: I am almost a newbie. I tried to upvote (clicked the little trangle above zero) but it says "thanks for the feedback! votes cast by those with less than 15 bla bla bla" :) I couldnt find the "answer accepted" button or so, sorry :)